# Flatpickr onchange event set dateStr to -1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I have 2 date pickers. Start Date and End Date. When the Start Date is selected I need the End Date to only allow the current selected Start Date minus one day.

Start Date

```
var date1 = $('[data-toggle="startDate"]').flatpickr(
  {
    enableTime: false,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    minDate: new Date().fp_incr(2),
    onChange: function(dateObj, dateStr) {
      date2.set('maxDate', dateStr)
    }
  }
);
```

End Date

```
var date2 = $('[data-toggle="endDate"]').flatpickr(
  {
     enableTime: true,
     altInput: true,
     altFormat: "F j, Y h:i K",
     dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
  }
);
```

On the Start Date how can I add `fp_incr(-1)` to the onChange: dateStr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a new Date object.
`date2.set('maxDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(-1))`